# i want to insert a record to my db in second activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I am new on Android programming. So that, I'll use wrong technical words, sorry for that ;)
i ve an app. in this app, `onCreate`, im checking if my db is created ( this check is for first time use ), if my db isn't created yet I'm routing user to a second layout( or activty. i couldnt be sure whch one is right word ). in this activity, when i try to create a SQLiteDatabase parameter im having a null pointer exception.
Here is a part of MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  VeriTabani veritabani; // vertiabani means database in turkish 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {

    if(db_flag==0)
    {

      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondClass.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my VeriTabani.java;

```
public class VeriTabani extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
   static final String VeriTabani="DATABASENAME";
   static final int version=1;
   public VeriTabani(Context context) {
     super(context, VeriTabani, null, version);
   }    

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  TABLENAME ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, xxx STRING,yyy STRING );");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST TABLENAME");
      onCreate(db);
   }
}
```

And, here is my SecondClass.java;

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity 
{
     VeriTabani veritabani;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
              SQLiteDatabase db=veritabani.getWritableDatabase(); 
              ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
              cv.put("xxx", another_parameter);
              //...
           }
           //...
        }
     }
}
```

im having error on this line;

SQLiteDatabase db=veritabani.getWritableDatabase();

I'm using same VeriTabani class to insert records to DB in MainActivity and it works perfectly. i couldnt undertand what is wrong when i use same code block in another activity.
i guess solve is simple but i couldnt get it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you have just declared your variable

```
 VeriTabani veritabani;
```

you haven't initialized that variable. you need to initialize it on onCreate() method.

```
 veritabani = new VeriTabani(YourActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

> im having error on this line;
>
> ```
> SQLiteDatabase db=veritabani.getWritableDatabase();
> ```

Looks like you didn't initialize your `veritabani` variable.

Add the following to that activity's `onCreate()`:

```
veritabani = new VeriTabani(this);
```